# Errors with table

Tags: tables, errors, longtable, hline

I am very new to the latex community (1 week) and writing my thesis with latex.

I am trying to built a table using the following code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable} [c] { |m{3cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|}
        \caption{Rating scale for total growth area \label{GrowTable}}
            \hline 
            \centering Total Growth Area (m$^2$) & \centering 100 or less & \centering 100-115 & \centering 115-130 & \centering 130-145 & \centering 145 or more
            \hline
            \centering Rating & \centering \cellcolor{red} 1 & \centering \cellcolor{red} 2 & \centering \cellcolor{yellow} 3 & \centering \cellcolor{green} 4 & \centering \cellcolor{green} 5 
            \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

It gives me the exact table I want but also provides errors which I do not know how to omit:

1. Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \centering
2. Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \end
3. Misplaced \noalign. \hline
4. Misplaced \omit. \centering
5. Misplaced \omit. \end

Current version of table that I want and is the output but with errors:
[image: Current version of table that I want and is the output but with errors]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You must place line-ending indicators (double backslash) at the ends of lines.

Comment: Thank you :-) I had that already but it still gave the same errors.

Comment: people can only comment on the code that you post, that has no `\\ `. It is always best to provide a _complete_ small example that produces the error that you are asking about. You also need `\arraybackslash` after the `\centering`. Unrelated but do not put a `center` enviornment around longtable.

Comment: Add the missing three `\\ ` and remove all the occurences of `\centering`. If you want to horizontally center the contents in the columns, you might want to use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}` or even diefine you own new column type.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you've provided so far, here is how I would structure the table:

- I'd use a `tabularx` environment, set its width to `\textwidth`, and let LaTeX calculate the widths of the five data columns.
- While it looks like a good idea to center the contents of the five data cplumns, the material in the left-most column probably looks better if it's typeset ragged-right (aka flushleft).
- Use en-dashes to "connect" numbers, i.e., write `100--115` rather than `100-115`, etc.
- Set the parameter `\extrarowheight` to a small positive length, e.g., `2pt`, in order to give the table a more open "look". While on the subject of giving the table a more open and inviting "look", do please get rid of all vertical lines. They're simply not needed, unless one is a big fan of the "prison cell" look...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \caption{Rating scale for total growth area} \label{GrowTable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} M{2.5cm} *{5}{C}  }
    \hline
    Total Growth Area (m$^2$) 
    & $\le100$ & 100--115 &  115--130 & 130--145 & $\ge145$ \\
    \hline
        Rating & \cellcolor{red} 1   & \cellcolor{red} 2   & \cellcolor{yellow} 3 
               & \cellcolor{green} 4 & \cellcolor{green} 5 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mico, Leandriis and David Carlisle!!! You are awesome!!!!!

I didn't have user package array but now I do and I defined a new column! :-D

```
\begin{table} 
    \centering
    \caption{Rating scale for total growth area \label{GrowTable}}
    \begin{tabular}{| M{2cm} | M{2cm} | M{2cm} | M{2cm} | M{2cm} | M{2cm} |}
    \hline 
        Total Growth Area (m$^2$) & 100 or less & 100-115 &  115-130 & 130-145 & 145 or more \\
    \hline
        Rating & \cellcolor{red} 1 & \cellcolor{red} 2 & \cellcolor{yellow} 3 &  \cellcolor{green} 4 & \cellcolor{green} 5 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Worked!!!! :-)

Comment: Could you please extend your code to a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages and your newly defined column type? By the way, on this site you can easily highlight code by selecting it and using the `{}` button or by pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: So that future readers of this posting have a fighting chance to understand what's going on in the code, it would be very helpful if you noted which document class you employ, which packages you load, and how the `M` column type is defined.